# Google maps - Navigate to a specific location on span click

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have small project in which users view a place cards which contains some information about the place such (schools,restaurants,institutes,...) and on that card I have a span with class of `visit-location` which has two attributes of lat and lng of the location and if has been clicked it should opens a page called map.php and load the map with the location in the center now I've written the code for loading the map but I'm confused about sending the lat and lng attributes to the map when it loads .. I'll provide my code bellow for any edits or changes
Edit: I have the error from the console says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"
span tag code in html:

```
<span class="visit-location" lat="12.7855" lng="45.0187">Visit in map</span>
```

span click function:

```
$('.visit-location').click(function(){
    var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
    var lng = $(this).attr('lng');
    loadMap(lat,lng);
    window.location.href='map.php';
});
```

load map function:

```
function loadMap(lat,lng){
    var aden = {lat: lat , lng: lng}; 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
        zoom: 15,
        center: aden,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false
    });
}
```

map.php code where I call the map:

```
<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

map api key as provided in the script tag:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/
js?key=mykey&callback=loadMap"> 
</script>
```

Comment: Please show the context of the page where you are calling loadMap. Also, are you seeing any error messages in the browser console? (Be sure to remove your API key).

Comment: @webprojohn sir I've edited my code can you look on it now

Comment: I think the `lat` and `lng` parameters are undefined because google doesn't pass arguments to the callback. Calling loadMap in your click handler won't impact the map shown after navigating to map.php. When `window.location.href` is changed, a new pages is loaded. I think the actual execution taking place consists of the following: load map.php, send the request to google (script tag), then run `loadMap` when the response from google comes in (callback parameter in the script src url).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use local storage to hold the map center state:

```
$('.visit-location').click(function(){
    var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
    var lng = $(this).attr('lng');
    // loadMap(lat,lng);
    localStorage.setItem('aden', JSON.stringify({ lat: lat, lng: lng }))
    window.location.href='map.php';
});
```

on maps.php:

```
function loadMap(){
    var aden = JSON.parse(localStoarage.getItem('aden'))
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
        zoom: 15,
        center: aden,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, one could use url parameters or cookies to do the same. One advantage of using url parameters is that users can bookmark the view with the location state.

Comment: @raizada-dev Let me know if something is unclear with this answer and I will happily improve it.

Comment: @ webprojohn after adding your code I get this error from the console "Uncaught ReferenceError: localStoarage is not defined"

Comment: sir I've provided a working code after small edits can you see it and tell me about it

Answer (score 0):

Based on @webprojohn answer I tried to use localStorage in a different way like this and it works

```
$('.visit-location').click(function(){
    var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
    var lng = $(this).attr('lng');
    localStorage.setItem('lat', lat);
    localStorage.setItem('lng', lng);
    window.location.href='map.php';
});  
function loadMap(){
    var aden = {lat: parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('lat')) , lng: parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('lng'))};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
        zoom: 15,
        center: aden,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false
    });
}
```